# Full Structural Survey for Listed, Managed Building

Tags: structural

I'm in the process of buying a flat which is set in the grounds of an 18th century hospital which, as such, is a listed development (under British legislation). The flats are managed by a Management Company who look after the structural integrity and preservation of the development.

My question is; do I still need to arrange a full structural survey, bearing in mind that grounds are preserved and maintained by the management company?

Comment: ...appreciate that this sort of question seems to uncommon here - happy to take on feedback if it should be posted elsewhere :)

Comment: do they provide indemnity? if so, I wouldn't worry about a survey...

Comment: You never *need* a survey to buy any property under English law.  However, most mortgage lenders will require one before they lend.  You should ask your lender - assuming you are borrowing.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how old the flat itself is, and what it's built of.

If it were actually in an 18th Century listed building, then you should definately have a full structural survey and also a specialist asbestos report as there could easily be asbestos remaining in the structure.

If it's a new development in the grounds, then treat as any other flat of the same age and structure. Management companies are not always well-run, they may not always be assertive enough at getting money to pay for maintenance, and the building may have been under-maintained for years.

Also check exactly what the listing encompasses and your responsibility for contributing to maintenance of the 18th Century building as listed building work can be very expensive - and a criminal offence if a listed building is altered or damaged without permission.

Comment: +1 for acknowledging maintenance is an issue for longevity of structural integrity.